# Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.GrayFilter is not a function

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm trying to apply the gray filter to an image

This is a fragment of code

```
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var slice = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("path.jpg");
var grayFilter = new  PIXI.GrayFilter();
slice.filters = [ grayFilter];
stage.addChild(slice);
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.GrayFilter is not a function. I use Google
>   Chrome.

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you did not include `src/pixi/filters/GrayFilter.js` in your source. Make sure that that file is being loaded after the main PIXI js file (and that it is being loaded).

Comment: So I need include GrayFilter.js, oops!!. I thought that it was sufficient with include PIXI.js only. . You refer to something like this `// add core plugins.
.....
core.filters        = require('./filters');
.....`